# HTMX indicator moves content down instead of replacing it

Tags: htmx

I am using HTMX and I created a loading indicator. The indicator is triggered and everything works as expected except for one thing.

The indicator is displayed above my content instead of hiding/replacing it. This looks really crappy and I am working on it for ages to fix this - without any luck.

Here's my HTML code:

```html
<a href="#financial-data" data-toggle="tab"
   hx-indicator=".loader"
   hx-get="/my/url"
   hx-trigger="click, budget-saved from:body"
   hx-target="#financial-data"
   hx-swap="innerHTML">Click me</a>
<div class="tab-pane" id="financial-data">
    <div class="loader htmx-indicator"></div>
</div>
```

I tried to catch the event but this a) doesn't work and b) feels super hacky:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('htmx:beforeSend', (e) => {
    if('hx-indicator' in e.target.attributes) {
        $(e.detail.target).html('<div class="loader htmx-indicator"></div>');                
    }
});
```

Any ideas what I've been doing wrong? I can't be the first person to struggle with this, right?

**Edit:**

The API would return something like this:

```html
<div class="loader htmx-indicator"></div>
<table><tr><td>My data</td></tr></table>
```

Here is my CSS for the loader:

```css
.loader {
    display: none;
}

.htmx-request .loader {
    display: block;
}

.htmx-request.loader {
    display: block;
}
```

Thx!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. The `#financial-data` div should not contain the indicator's div at all after the swap. Does the response contain the indicator div?

Comment: I tried around with this. Yes, true, if you leave it like this, after the first refresh the indicator is gone. But this is not my issue 

Comment: Then what is your issue? HTMX swaps the target, so if the response does not contain a new, non-functioning indicator, neither will the target. Could you show an example response from the endpoint?

Comment: I updated my question. I need the indicator before the call (obviously), so if I replace everything, the response has to contain it again - which is fine for me.

Comment: I'm still unable to reproduce this. When I add the indicator's div to the response data it also becomes invisible after the request. HTMX has the class `.htmx-indicator` which hides it by `opacity: 0`. It becomes visible only during the request. Can you check that your indicator div is hidden by default? Maybe some other CSS class overrides it.

Comment: True, I use custom CSS. Maybe this is the issue... I update my post.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your problem. You were talking about the second (and so on) request when a previously loaded content is already present on the page. See my answer for an easy fix.

Answer (score 5):

We can also use HTMX's indicator feature to hide the previously loaded content that is present on the page after first request.

In the response we add a new class to the main content that we want to hide during the new request:

```
<div class="loader htmx-indicator"></div>
<table class="loaded-content"><tr><td>My data</td></tr></table>
```

Then we tell HTMX that we have two indicator targets: the real one with `.loader` and the content with `.loaded-content` class:

```
<a href="#financial-data" data-toggle="tab"
   hx-indicator=".loader,.loaded-content"
   hx-get="/my/url"
   hx-trigger="click, budget-saved from:body"
   hx-target="#financial-data"
   hx-swap="innerHTML">Click me</a>
<div class="tab-pane" id="financial-data">
    <div class="loader htmx-indicator"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS definitions:

```
.loader {
    display: none;
}

.htmx-request .loader {
    display: block;
}

.htmx-request.loader {
    display: block;
}

/* Hide previously loaded content during HTMX request */
.htmx-request .loaded-content {
    display: none;
}

.htmx-request.loaded-content {
    display: none;
}
```

So when the user clicks on the button, HTMX will add the `.htmx-request` class to both indicator targets. The CSS rules make the real indicator visible and the previously loaded content invisible during the request.

Comment: Thx for your post! Its super weird, when putting a breakpoint, your (slightly modified) changes work. Without the debugger, it doesnt. WTF

Comment: Maybe the response is quicker then the fading animation? I created a slow endpoint (2s) for the test, and it worked fine, I was able to see the changes in browser dev console.

Comment: I had the same idea but no, thats not the issue... :(

Comment: And what do you see? The content receives the `.htmx-request` class during the request, but remains visible?

Comment: As I said, when I put a debugger on the point, where the element gets removed, all is looking good. When I don't use the debugger then the element is never hidden, no matter how long the request takes.

Comment: I mean what happens at the DOM level. If you inspect the content's div during the request, you can see HTMX adds the `.htmx-request` class. Then you can see what CSS rules are active on the element. For example if a different CSS class somehow overrules the `display: none;` property you can see that during the request. If `.htmx-request` class is present during the request on the content's element, then HTMX did its job and the problem has a different origin.